# Issues with joining multiple tables

Tags: join, left-join, inner-join

I'm really struggling at the moment trying to work out how to join multiple tables without duplicating data.
At the moment I have 8 tables that I was wanted to get various information from per member of staff like the below:

SDQ score, Goal scores, CHI score, number of appointments, number of dna appointments

The tables and field I can see to join are as follows

tblSDQ - Assessed_By_Staff_ID

tblGoals - Recorded_By_Staff_ID

tblCHI - Recorded_By_Staff_ID

tblReferral - Staff_ID

tblStaff - Staff_ID

tblDiaryAppointment - needs to connect to tblDiaryAppointmentClinician using Clinician_Invitee_Staff_ID

I hope someone can help or advice. I just don't know if it's even possible to join all these tables using the same field, or if its possible to join them but then return a number of entries but then just count others?

Answer (score 0):

Syntax depends on a rdbms you are using.

You could use join with specified join fields from both tables:

```
select bla-bla
from table1
join table2 on ( table1.fileld_name1 = table2.fileld_name2 )
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html

if you need outer join (to show nulls for optional tables data) you could use this:

```
join table2 on ( table1.fileld_name1 = table2.fileld_name2 or table2.field_name2 is null )
```

to join with couns you could use subqueries like this

```
join ( select field_name3, coint(*) as cnt from table3 goup by field_name3 ) AS table3_counts
...
where ( table3_counts.field_name3 = ... or table3_counts.field_name3 is null )
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/from-clause-subqueries.html

PS: Joins are often slow. It's better to denormalize tables to eliminate joins and gain performance. Or do simple selects and join in backend code.